# Does a continuous and surjective function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb Q$ exist?

Tags: calculus, continuity

My intuiton says that the answer is no, but I don't know how to prove it. I think the problem is in the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q$... Any hint?

Comment: hint: connectedness

Comment: @Timkinsella : Connectedness is not normally introduced until well after the intermediate value theorem. And the latter is plenty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuous Functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112043/continuous-functions-from-mathbbr-to-mathbbq)

Comment: @MichaelHardy, how would you use IVT if the codomain is $\mathbb{Q}$? I thought the generalization of IVT to other codomains was the concept of connectedness.

Comment: @Ethan, is this really a ***calculus*** question?! Or is it a topology question?

Answer (score 1):

Since f is continuous and takes only rational value , so the function must be a constant one :
If not constant then obviously there will exist two real numbers a and b so that f(a) and f(b) are unequal. Since f is continuous then by intermediate value property f must take on all the values lying between f(a) and f(b) , which contradicts that f takes only rational values .
Since f is a constant function, it can't be a surjective one.